# C# Linq EF Core Ordering the "resulting groups" by substring of group key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a Ef core linq query where I want to group the records by "VehicleNo" string then order the resulting groups by the substring of the group key.

```
var theGroup = Model.CreditSaleMaster.GroupBy(dd => dd.ProductSaleMaster.VehicleNo).OrderBy(d => 
d.Key.Substring(d.Key.Length - 4, 4));
```

Though there is no error while the above code executes, The resulting groups child entities like productsalemaster are returning null.

What I want to achieve is to first Group the results with Productsalemaster.VehicleNo and then "Order the resulting groups" by the substring of last 4 digits of vehicle number.

For example three vehicle number groups resulting as AP012S0222, TR03M2012, TS07R0222 in alphabetical order. Take the result group and then order the groups based on the last four digits of the group key i.e., vehicle number so that the result should be the group collection should be sorted like AP012S0222,TS07R0222,TR03M2012. I hope it answers my concern.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Please add your current result and expected result as well.

Comment: I have added the expected results. please see above.

Comment: What do you mean by that `The resulting groups child entities like productsalemaster are returning null.`. You can group items based on `Productsalemaster.VehicleNo` and sort it, right?

Comment: That's the problem. After grouping the item on VehicleNo. how I can sort the groups by they group key? the example was mentioned above in the question description.

Comment: So this `.OrderBy(d => d.Key.Substring(d.Key.Length - 4, 4));`  does not work?

Comment: ```var theGroup = Model.CreditSaleMaster.GroupBy(dd => dd.ProductSaleMaster.VehicleNo).OrderBy(d => 
d.Key.Substring(d.Key.Length - 4, 4));``` This code returns group with null Productsalemasters. I need to know how to get the groups sorted that is after grouping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209752/discussion-between-techsha-and-selim-yildiz).

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
var theGroup = Model.CreditSaleMaster
    .GroupBy(dd => dd.ProductSaleMaster.VehicleNo)
    .Include(ddd => ddd.ProductSaleMaster)
    .OrderBy(d => d.Key.Substring(d.Key.Length - 4, 4));
```

Comment: I am grouping the items in Razor View and i am getting error like IQueryable<IGrouping<string,CreditSaleMaster> does not contain a definition for 'Include'. This does not work.